# How to fix undefined variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

For some reason my function is not returning a 1 or 2 even though it's specifically setup to do so. What am I doing wrong? I'm looking at the chrome dev tools and it's telling me that var `processed` is `undefined`.

I'm quite stumped on this. I've been reading if it's because a variable could be used as a parameter but I'm not sure if this is the case

```
var processChoices = function (player, computer){
    switch (player) {
        case player == 'rock':
            if (computer == 'paper'){
                var winner = 2; 
            } else if (computer == 'scissors'){
                var winner = 1; 
            }
            break;
        case player == 'paper':
            if (computer == 'scissors'){
                var winner = 2;
            } else if (computer == 'rock'){
                var winner = 1;
            }
            break;
        case player == 'scissors':
            if (computer == 'rock'){
                var winner = 2;
            } else if (computer == 'paper'){
                var winner = 1;
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (computer == player){
        var winner = console.log('We have a tie, go again!');
            } 
            break;
    }
    return winner
}

var determineWinner = function (){
    var computer = computerPlay();
    var player = playerChoice();
    var processed = processChoices(player, computer);

    if (processed == 1){
        playerCount += 1;
    } else {
        computerCount += 1;
    }
    var message = (processed == 2) ? `The computer wins! ${computer} beats ${player}!` : `The player wins! ${player} beats ${computer}!`;
    console.log(message);

}
```

I'm expecting the output of var `processed` to be 1 or 2. It's coming back as `undefined`.

Comment: It is because you don't have a condition where `player` is the same as the `computer` except in the default which will most likely never run (aka `player == 'rock' && computer == 'rock'`)

Comment: plus define `var winner` once before the switch, then do only `winner = ...`

Comment: `var winner = console.log('');` assigns `undefined` to `winner`. `console.log` does not return anything.

Comment: You also (possibly) don't have every possible case covered, since `default` contains another `if`

Comment: Would you mind pasting the complete code? your 2 functions's code needs a lot of refactoring as well, have you followed a beginners guide on OOP programming?

Comment: @James There is nothing about this to indicate that he is using OOP...

Comment: @Paulpro Ugh, true although JavaScript shares some OOP characteristics, that wasn't my point, dully noted though. But let's not make it a third-party discussion, he needs some basics of programming and debugging. Also as I said, there are functions being used that are not being written down to do proper debugging (and refactoring, wouldn't take much time).

Comment: The format is not `switch (player) { case player == 'rock': ... }` it's `switch (player) { case 'rock': ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the `switch` statement correctly. Your `case` statements need to just be the value that you want to match. See below.

It's would also be good to declare the variable `winner` once.

```js
var processChoices = function(player, computer) {
  var winner = 0;
  switch (player) {
    case 'rock':
      if (computer == 'paper') {
        winner = 2;
      } else if (computer == 'scissors') {
        winner = 1;
      }
      break;
    case 'paper':
      if (computer == 'scissors') {
        winner = 2;
      } else if (computer == 'rock') {
        winner = 1;
      }
      break;
    case 'scissors':
      if (computer == 'rock') {
        winner = 2;
      } else if (computer == 'paper') {
        winner = 1;
      }
      break;
    default:
      if (computer == player) {
        console.log('We have a tie, go again!');
      }
      break;
  }
  return winner
}

var computer = "rock";
var player = "paper";
console.log("Player chose:", player, "Computer chose:", computer);
console.log("The winner is...", processChoices(player, computer));
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much! I realized that the variable only existed in the switch function. Which now makes sense. Also great tip on setting the variable only once. This  is the first time that I've posted in this and I was really nervous I was going to get a lot of hate for something so simple.

Answer (score -1):

First off the switch format is wrong.

```
switch (player) {
  case player == 'rock':  // wrong
  case 'rock':            // correct
```

Second you need to check all states of computer or else check at the end

```
var processChoices = function (player, computer){
    let winner = 0;
    switch (player) {
        case 'rock':
            if (computer === 'paper'){
                winner = 2; 
            } else if (computer === 'scissors'){
                winner = 1; 
            }
            break;
        case 'paper':
            if (computer === 'scissors'){
                winner = 2;
            } else if (computer === 'rock'){
                winner = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 'scissors':
            if (computer === 'rock'){
                winner = 2;
            } else if (computer === 'paper'){
                winner = 1;
            }
            break;
    }

    if (winner === 0) {
      console.log('We have a tie, go again!');
    }

    return winner
}
```

ps:

- use `const` and `let`. Don't use `var'
- use `===` not `==`

Also the entire thing can be a lot smaller

```
const winnerTable = {
  rock: {
    rock: 0,
    paper: 2,
    scissors: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    rock: 1,
    paper: 0,
    scissors: 2,
  },
  scissors: {
    rock: 2,
    paper: 1,
    scissors: 0,
  },
};

var processChoices = function (player, computer){
  return winnerTable[player][computer];
};
```

Comment: Your small suggestion will throw an error on bad input

Comment: Sure, and the original code will silently fail. So what. The question isn't about validation.

Answer (score -2):

well I guess it's in var determineWinner u called 
var processed = processChoices(player, computer);
and processChoices is a var not a function with parameters
=>delete (player, computer);